# Unable to set messge ids for jms message while using citrus frame work to execute xml test case that puts message in Websphere MQ

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, citrus-framework

I am using citrus integration framework to execute test cases that puts messages in IBM websphere MQ. When I am sending special headers with jms message headers. I am able to set correlation ID as mentioned in the header but I am unable to set messageID. Here is the headers I am sending

```
    <send endpoint="QueueEndPoint">
      <message>
      <resource="file:c:\payloads\payload.xml">
      <message>
      <header>
       <element name="Scenario" value="some thing"/>
       <element  name="instanceID" value="some thing"/>
       <element name="citrus_jms_correlationId" value="012345678910111213141516"/>  
<element name="citrus_jms_messageId" value="012345678910111213143121"/>
      </header>
```

[here is the message id and correlation Id appearing in IBM MQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8tGL.png)

Comment: Please provide and explanation of what actually happens.

Comment: After placing the message in the MQ. correlation id is appearing as it is in the MQ but message id is not the value I have given. I dont know weather mq is not accepting the Message ID value or CItrus is doing some thing but the message id I am seeing in the MQ was default Message ID generated by MQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad idea, very bad idea to set the MessageId in MQ.  Let MQ set and control the MessageId.  Setting the CorrelationId is what you should be setting.

The screen-shot shows that you set the CorrelationId to '161514131211109876543212' which is Hex='313631353134313331323131313039383736353433323132'.

Answer (score 1):

The JMS standard says that MessageId CANNOT be set by applications:

> When a message is sent, JMSMessageID is ignored. When the send method
>   returns it contains a provider-assigned value.

Although it is possible to override that in an extension provided by the MQ JMS classes, it requires [additional settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032330_.htm) where you explicitly state you want to do that override of the standard.